# How to apply federation to an existing table

Tags: asp.net, sql, azure, federation

Am very new to azure federation.In my project there is an SQL azure database and now we want to use azure federation for scaling that database.

Is it possible to Federate the existing table ?.

How can I achieve this on my existing table casedetails. Am planning to federate the table based on customer_Id.From where should i begin.

in my scenario casedetails table against customerid which is the FK from Customer table.

Will it affect the queries used in the existing web application to fetch and insert values to the database ?.

How can i migrate data into the federated databse.. I am also facing a problem from identity not supported in federation. few of my tables contains identity specification and lots of data. Please reply if u have any insight relating to the problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you looked at this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh848258.aspx

Comment: Ya.. But it describes on federation at table creation itself. In my scenario all are set except federation.

Comment: I believe you cannot federate existing tables. You need to migrate the date into a federated database to support federation.

Comment: Sry I didn't get you fully.. Could you please  elaborate a little.

Comment: @Chandermani How can i migrate data into the federated databse.. I am also facing a problem from identity not supported in federation. few of my tables contains identity specification and lots of data. Please reply if u have any insight relating to the problem.